# C# serialization failure - workarounds?

Tags: c#, serialization, binary, readonly, binaryformatter

The program below results in the following failure:

```
Field in TypedReferences cannot be static or init only
```

Based on this, the obvious fix is:

1. remove `readonly` modifier on `private readonly T _value`

However, the following two changes also eliminate the failure:

2. change `struct Data` to `class Data`
3. change `public int[] Content` to `public int Content`

Does anyone know what's going on in the internals of BinaryFormatter that allow serialization to proceed in cases #2 and #3?

---

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace SerializationStumper {

    // *** helper

    public static class Serializer {
        public static MemoryStream SerializeToStream<T>(T o)
        {
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(stream, o);
            return stream;
        }

        public static T DeserializeFromStream<T>(MemoryStream stream)
        {
            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return (T)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        }

        public static T RoundTrip<T>(T v) {
            return DeserializeFromStream<T>(SerializeToStream<T>(v));
        }
    }

    // *** set up data structures

    [Serializable]
    public struct Wrapped<T> {
        private readonly T _value;

        public Wrapped(T value) {
            _value = value;
        }   
    }

    [Serializable]
    public struct Data {
        public int[] Content;
    }

    // *** Perform test

    public class Program {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var wrapped = new Wrapped<Data>(new Data { Content = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 } } ); 
            var roundtrip = Serializer.RoundTrip(wrapped);  
            Console.WriteLine(roundtrip);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A full stack trace tells us the code fails here: [ArgumentException: Field in TypedReferences cannot be static or init only.]
   System.TypedReference.MakeTypedReference(Object target, FieldInfo[] flds)  and within that method the specific checks that throw it is : if (runtimeFieldInfo.IsInitOnly || runtimeFieldInfo.IsStatic)
          throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Argument_TypedReferenceInvalidField")); so i think the difference between the class and the struct has something to do with how they are loaded via the parsing in the ObjectManager. i.e different attribs

Comment: It might be that Serialization.ObjectManager.DoValueTypeFixup gets called for the struct and not for the class. DoValueTypeFixup in turn calls TypedReference.MakeTypedReference. I'm not in a position to step through the source but you if load up the symbols and do so it should become clear(er).

Answer (score 0):

Since no one else has answered yet, I'll take a stab...

It serializes fine, but the deserialization fails.

I don't know this for sure, but I suspect that it is because as a struct, the deserializer doesn't know how big this array is:

```
    public int[] Content;
```

so it doesn't know how many bytes to read to fill the array.
As a class, it probably serializes the length into the data.

If you serialize as both a struct and as a class to different files, they do have slightly different content, and one of the additional bytes in the serialized class is the number 3, which I'm guessing is the array length. Though I haven't studied up on the binary output format to be sure.

The "fix" probably has something to do with [fixed size buffers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zycewsya.aspx) so that the deserializer would know how many bytes of the data stream make up the array. I haven't made a working solution that uses them though.

*edit: It seems you cannot serialize a fixed size buffer, so ignore the above.*

So #2 would work because it serializes the array length into the data stream, and #3 works because in `int` is a fixed byte size.

Comment: The array length is serialized into the stream for both a struct and a class so that wont be the reason re: #2 The extra length in the file for when Data is a class vs a struct is just the difference in header length for a class vs a struct. i.e. this for struct 020000000200000005 and this for class 02000000020000000903000000050300000015. If you change the number of elements in the array neither of these headers change. That information including array length is encoded for the Content property and it's serialized bytes don't change for struct vs class.

Comment: A 3 element array is encoded as follows: 07080200000009040000000F0400000003000000080100000002000000030000000B and a 4 element array like this 07080200000009040000000F040000000400000008010000000200000003000000040000000B where 000F040000000300 vs 000F040000000400 has the length encoding and doesn't change if you change the struct vs class.